# How to secure Custom Webhook hosted on Azure App Service for capturing Azure monitor Alert

Tags: webhooks, azure-appservice

I am working on creation of custom webhook that will get invoke whenever alerts will be generated by Azure monitor. How can I ensure traffic from Azure monitor is within Azure backbone network and not hitting internet when webhook is invoked.

Thanks a lot in advance
Parag

Comment: Are you building your receiving webhook in azure appservice? I suggest you read this https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service/networking/private-endpoint

Comment: is there a specific workbook related part of this question?  i see "webhook" but not "workbook" in the question, but it is in the tags.

Comment: Also make sure that azure monitor doesn't already natively provide whatever functionality you are building in your webhook

Comment: Thanks Nick I have gone through the link. Can I setup private link in Azure monitor Webhook? Will it work or i need to use AMPLS

Comment: Good question - I'm not too sure. Applying private link to Azure web apps ensure the destination is private, but possibly you need to also apply AMPLS to ensure the origin is also private

Comment: AMPLS is from various Azure resources to Azure monitor resource. Is it support vice versa. In my scenario we want to call webhook hosted on Azure App Service from Monitor

Comment: The link in my very first comment explains how to isolate Azure App Service to a VNET

Answer (score 0):

Azure App Service has network restriction option. Under network restriction it allows Azure service tag. Action group service tag allows accessing custom webjook hosted on Azure App service in restricted way.